# Within a team work space can I have local variables that are not saved to the team work space (cloud)

Tags: postman

I want to know if it is possible to have a set of local variables that I can use in my team work space but will not be saved.

For example I want to use some auth credentials across multiple tests but do not want them to be saved on postmans cloud.

I believe I can achieve this in Newman using `--global-var "<global-variable-name>=<global-variable-value>"` but it would be great to make it possible through the GUI.

I have looked online and read Postman's documentation in particular the variable page which talks in detail about:

> - Global
> - Environment
> - Local
> - Data

None of these seem to do what I require.

Answer (score 0):

If you just set the variable as the `Current Value` it won't get synced to the Postman servers and stay local to your machine:

[image: Postman]

This is part of Postman `sessions` - More details can be found here https://blog.getpostman.com/2018/08/09/sessions-faq/